# Is it possible to remove Route objects from a RouteCollection object?

Tags: 8, routes

When I look at the code used for the method handling a [RoutingEvents::DYNAMIC](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!RoutingEvents.php/constant/RoutingEvents%3a%3aDYNAMIC/8) event, which receives a [RouteBuildEvent](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!RouteBuildEvent.php/class/RouteBuildEvent/8) object, I notice the code is always similar to the following one.

```
$collection = $event->getRouteCollection();
$route = new Route("$path/display", array('_form' => '\Drupal\field_ui\DisplayOverview') + $defaults, array('_permission' => 'administer ' . $entity_type . ' display'));
$collection->add("field_ui.display_overview.$entity_type", $route);
```

Since the [RouteCollection](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!symfony!routing!Symfony!Component!Routing!RouteCollection.php/class/RouteCollection/8) class defines the [RouteCollection::remove()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!symfony!routing!Symfony!Component!Routing!RouteCollection.php/function/RouteCollection%3a%3aremove/8) method, would not removing routes from the collection be possible? I was thinking of removing a route to redefine it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a `RoutingEvents::ALTER` event, which runs afterward.

You can think of the difference between `RoutingEvents::DYNAMIC` and `RoutingEvents::ALTER` as similar to the difference between `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()`.

There is a [Views issue](https://drupal.org/node/2027115) that discusses *replacing* routes, as opposed to removing and adding them, perhaps follow their example.